# Magento 2: Upgrading a "Meta Package" Install

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, setup, magento-community

A while back, I installed Magento 2 via the [composer meta-package](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html).  This is also known as the integrator install.

This appears to have installed Magento CE 2.0.1.  Is there a way to upgrade this version to the latest Magento CE 2.0.3?  I realize I could update the `composer.json` so that the 2.0.1 here

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.1",
```

becomes

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.0.3",
```

However, that would miss files like

```
app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php
```

As well as any updates to the composer.json file itself.

Is it possible to update a version of Magento 2 installed with the meta package?  Or is this not the intent of the meta packages?

Comment: http://alankent.me/2016/03/31/m2-project-source-code-management-recommendation/ might have some useful information. I believe NonComposerComponentRegistration.php *will* be updated when you do the upgrade due to the magento installer plugin for Composer. If there is a new 'magento2-base' module, it will replace the files previously installed by the base module. Article recommends "use git" to preserve local changes. You can fine the default file https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php, which gets package into the "magento2-base" package.

Comment: "I believe NonComposerComponentRegistration.php will be updated" that's a negative -- or, at least, in my specific instance moving from 2.0.1 to 2.0.3 the composer upgrade didn't install NonComposerComponentRegistration.php, and didn't update app/etc/di.xml.

Comment: You can update the metapackage with System Upgrade or from the command line. *Caveat* at this moment we're replacing 2.0.3 with 2.0.4 and access to `repo.magento.com` is blocked. Wait for an announcement. Step 1, run `composer require <string> <version> --noupdate` (check the syntax). Step 2, run `composer update`. Step 3, run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: @SteveJohnson How will this update files outside of `vendor`?

Answer (score 3):

I just adjusted my `composer.json` file to use 2.0.4 instead of 2.0.2 (by hand), and afterwards ran `composer update` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Worked flawless in here.

I believe the Magento Composer installer package handles the installation of files in the `app/` etc. folders, which also updates stuff on upgrade. But, this last part is just assumption as I haven't had to debug it.

Comment: @alanstorm, Do either of these answers help?

Comment: @stefandoorn can you please open up the file `app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php` and confirm the year of the copyright

Comment: /**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

Comment: @KristofatFooman See above.

Answer (score 2):

I can currently not test it, as the composer repository of connect is broken, but I hope it's still useful.

That's my `composer.json` of my own project https://github.com/Cotya/DashboardProject/blob/6ce3f307c53a3fb54c94d8a7bd70b306036da928/composer.json

I changed recently to `"magento/product-community-edition": "^2.0"` to actually be able to update with a simple `composer update --with-dependencies magento/product-community-edition` command.
I always explicitly name what should be updated, to not mix it up with the other packages I require besides magento, but therefore I need the `--with-dependencies` argument.

A very important part of this workflow is to commit the `composer.lock` file after each (successfully tested) update. As you see the diff of the lock file is too big for GitHub, that's a result of all the dependency updates and the reason, why you should not mix up a magento update with an update of something else.

As you can see, I have defined the files for `NonComposerComponentRegistration` myself, you can have multiple of them.
Downside of my approach is, that when changes in the project `composer.json` happen, you need to apply them manually.

As you asked about the updating of the `NonComposerComponentRegistration` file, there are still a "few" files, which get copied out of vendor into the target directory, that's why I named it explicitly `build` to not mix up own with generated/copied stuff.

Hope that helps, even if this is quite a unique setup of M2.